# Complex extraction and transformation of multiple values within a column using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

**Background of how I obtained the 'df' Dataframe:**

This data is being pulled from SQL Server into Python and then converted to a dataframe using Pandas:

```
Backup = pyodbc.connect(
         'Driver={SQL Server};'
         'Server=test\SQLEXPRESS;'
         'Database=Backup;'
         'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
        )

crsr = Backup.cursor()

 for table_name in crsr.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
    print(table_name)
    cursor = Backup.cursor()
sql = "select TOP 20* from dbo.table$"

cursor.execute(sql)
for data in cursor.fetchall():
print (data)


df = pandas.read_sql(sql,Backup)
df
```

I have a column  within my  df dataframe that consists of values that look like this:

```
 Location

 AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
 AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
 AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
 GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
 GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
 GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
 SJC1 - DR Santa Clara
 IAD - Terremark NAV Culpepper
 HKG1 - Equin HK Hong Kong
```

Dilemma:

How would I extract only the actual places such as: Sao Paulo, Amsterdam, Culpepper, Hong Kong etc?

Desired output:

```
 Amsterdam
 Amsterdam
 Amsterdam
 São Paulo
 São Paulo
 São Paulo
 Santa Clara
 Culpepper
 Hong Kong
```

The problem is that I cannot just split on the last blank space, due to the countries that have two words, split by a blank space. (Hong Kong, Sao Paul)

What I have been working on:

```
df["New_Column"]= df["Location"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
```

I am also using str function (From a stackoverflow member suggestion)

```
df.str.extract()
```

Comment: Have a look into regex, it’s an excellent text pattern matching tool; for which you can use the `Series.str.extract` function, and extract the matched values (city names) into a new column.

Comment: Thank you. Ill research this

Comment: No worries, my pleasure.  Just popped an answer on to help explain further.

Comment: If list is small and doesn't change often, I'd go with plain dictionary mapping. This mapping could be keep in json file.

Comment: Ok this column has roughly 1 million rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this regular expression to work, it's a little involved so I'll break it down for you.

Create data:

```
data = """
AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
SJC1 - DR Santa Clara
IAD - Terremark NAV Culpepper
HKG1 - Equin HK Hong Kong
""".strip().split("\n")

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["location"])
df["location"] = df["location"].str.strip()

print(df)

                        location
0       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
1       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
2       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
3    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
4    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
5    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
6          SJC1 - DR Santa Clara
7  IAD - Terremark NAV Culpepper
8      HKG1 - Equin HK Hong Kong
```

Apply our regular expression via `Series.str.extract`

```
df["city"] = df["location"].str.extract(r"-.*\s+[A-Z0-9]+\s+(?P<city>.*)")

print(df)
                        location         city
0       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam    Amsterdam
1       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam    Amsterdam
2       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam    Amsterdam
3    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo    São Paulo
4    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo    São Paulo
5    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo    São Paulo
6          SJC1 - DR Santa Clara  Santa Clara
7  IAD - Terremark NAV Culpepper    Culpepper
8      HKG1 - Equin HK Hong Kong    Hong Kong
```

Regular expression explanation `r"-.*\s+[A-Z0-9]+\s+(?P<city>.*)$"`:

- `-` find the hypen. we can ignore everything that occurs before the hyphen.
- `\s+[A-Z0-9]\s+` Once we've found the hyphen, find a substring that contains only capital letters and/or numbers, additionally this substring must be surrounded by 1 or more spaces.
- `(?P<city>.*)$` Once we've found the previous step, consume the rest of the string as the name of the city and store it in a capture group.

While regular expressions are very useful tools, they do tend to leave a fair number of edge cases. The expression I have here works for your data, but make sure you do some testing and tweaking for your full dataset as it still may return NaN in some cases if your string does not match the pattern identified here.

Comment: Thank you Cameron, this helped alot. I was also wondering how would I distinguish if the city has a name, say, like this:  HONG KONG(test)                                 How would I include this in the logic? I am still learning regex and I see it is very valuable

Comment: to clarify, you're saying what if one of the values in your cell appears as follows: "HKG1 - Equin HK Hong Kong(test)" you want to know how to extract "Hong Kong" without extracting "Hong Kong(test)"

Comment: Yes, I am researching this now because it seems it may only extract Hong Kong(test), but perhaps I need to add another 'condition'

Comment: I would do a little bit of cleaning on the column before we try to extract the city name. Try running this before we perform the regular expression in my post. This will entirely remove any parentheses and everything between them that appear in your "location" column
`df["location"] = df["location"].str.replace("\(.+\)", "")`

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The user has stated the data is coming from SQL Server. As such, the sample code has been updated to show an example of the data extraction from SQL and subsequent city extraction. (Previously, the locations data was synthesised from a `list`.)

**Original commentary:**
As recommended in my comment, here is an example of how to use regex to parse the city from the location string.

Additionally, this example (optionally) makes use of the `unidecode` library which converts non-ASCII (extended unicode) characters to ASCII, as they may trip up the r
egex. It is a common practice to convert non-ASCII characters to ASCII in text processing procedures.

The regex pattern - although it may look a lot like gobbledy-gook, does the following:

- Starts are the beginning of the string to isolate the 'XX  -  ' pattern
- Isolates the following 'Xxxx' characters
- Isolates the 'XXN' to determine where to begin the named capture
- The named capture (indicated by the `?P<city>[\w\s]+` pattern) is used to extract the city name(s) into the `city` column

Note the use of the `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the string. These tell the pattern to start at the beginning (`^`) of the string and to match the pattern all the way to the end (`$`). Often, it's very useful to explicitly match an entire string. Otherwise, if only a partial string is matched, you might get unexpected results.

[Here is a link](https://regexr.com/) to a regex building/testing site I find very helpful when writing new patterns.

#### Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from unidecode import unidecode  # optional

# Database connection code ...
# ...
# ...

# Query data from SQL into a DataFrame.
# We use MySQL, so this line will be different for you;
# use your existing code here.
df = pd.read_sql(sql="select * from locations", con=engine)

# Define regex pattern.
exp = re.compile(r'^[A-Z0-9\s\-]+[\w\s]+[A-Z0-9]+\s(?P<city>[\w\s]+)$')
# Convert non-ASCII characters to ASCII. (optional)
# df['locations'] = df['locations'].apply(unidecode)    # Extract the city name.
df['cities'] = df['locations'].str.extract(exp, expand=True)
```

#### Raw data from SQL:

```
                       locations
0       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
1       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
2       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
3    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
4    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
5    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo
6          SJC1 - DR Santa Clara
7  IAD - Terremark NAV Culpepper
8      HKG1 - Equin HK Hong Kong
```

#### Parsed output:

```
                       locations       cities
0       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam    Amsterdam
1       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam    Amsterdam
2       AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam    Amsterdam
3    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo    São Paulo
4    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo    São Paulo
5    GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo    São Paulo
6          SJC1 - DR Santa Clara  Santa Clara
7  IAD - Terremark NAV Culpepper    Culpepper
8      HKG1 - Equin HK Hong Kong    Hong Kong
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error  
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'  When I run this script: df['locations'] = df['locations'].apply(unidecode)

Comment: Interesting. Is the `unidecode` library installed, and imported as `from unidecode import unidecode` ?  As a library test, you can save ‘São Paulo’ as a string and run `unidecode(‘São Paulo’` to help isolate the issue.

Comment: Hi, I used pip install unidecode and it installed correctly, then I used  from unidecode import unidecode....................the only change I did was: df = pd.DataFrame({'locations': [data]})   (added the [] brackets due to me getting a scalar error)

Comment: Is that because your list of locations is coming from a string or file (as shown in the other answer)?

Comment: The error says: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index - The list of locations comes from the pandas dataframe

Comment: It sounds like your DataFrame is being constructed differently from the one in my example, as 1) the `data` object is already a list, therefore the additional `[ ]` are not needed and the index should auto populate; per my example.  So, let’s start over ... what is the data source for the locations? CSV, JSON, web, another DataFrame ... ?  Please update the original question with the source data and I’ll have a look tomorrow morning, if that’s ok.  Cheers.

Comment: I will update this. The data is being imported from my SQL Server database, then within Python I am converting it to a pandas dataframe. I will update now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221677/discussion-between-s3dev-and-lynnette).